# Клик по ссылке python selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Активно изучаю selenium на python. Столкнулся с проблемой. На почте при первом входе нужно разрешить переход по ссылкам внутри письма. И вот не могу кликнуть по этой кнопке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать по тексту в кнопке методом `driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Разрешить')`- не сработало.
Так же пробовал `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'remote-objects-message > span.boxbuttons > a')`, но тоже глухо.
Постоянно ошибка `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="message-objects"]"}`

Каким способом или методом можно нажать на эту кнопку ?
Буду очень признателе за помощь.

Так же пробовал использовать `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick='rcmail.command('load-remote')']")`, но видимо не правильно задаю, потому что так и говорит мне python `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

Comment: А зачем это вообще нужно? Какая цель стоит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать следующий код:

```
link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#loadremote']")
link.click()
```

Comment: Да, так тоже пробовал, но получаю ```Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href='#loadremote']"}```

Сейчас повторил, чтобы убедиться, но результат тот же.
Не знаю, влияет ли тот факт, что данный блок находится во втором блоке ```html``` внутри блока ```<iframe name="messagecontframe" id="messagecontframe" aria-labelledby="aria-label-mailpreviewframe" src="skins/elastic/watermark.html" title="Предпросмотр сообщений"></iframe>```

Comment: Да, влияет, вам требуется переключиться на контекст iframe

`iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "messagecontframe")`
`driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`

после этого предоставленный мной код должен корректно работать

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Сработало. Изначально не досмотрел, что второй iframe есть, и методы отличаются. Буду внимательнее. чень помогли

Comment: Если моё решение вам помогло прошу отметить ответ как правильный. Спасибо. И удачи в программировании!)

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно для начала переключиться в iFrame, а после этого уже там искать элемент
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='`locator`']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)